# More complex Cypher Query as TraversalDescription

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I don't know, how to build the following cypher query as a TraversalDescription in Java:

```
START container=node(startContainerId), condition=node(startConditionId) MATCH container-[:CONTAINS*]->items-[*]->condition WHERE items.type! = 'instance' RETURN items
```

I could only realize the first part, to get all "items" in a given "container":

```
TraversalDescription td = Traversal.description().depthFirst()
                .relationships(Neo4JRelTypes.CONTAINS, Direction.OUTGOING).evaluator(new Evaluator() {

                    @Override
                    public Evaluation evaluate(Path path) {
                        if (path.endNode().getProperty("type").equals("instance")) {
                            return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
                        } else {
                            return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

But how can I filter these "items" with an outgoing relationship which matches a specific node?
I want to test the performance between this cypher query and an comparable TraversalDescription.

Thank you for helping.
Best regards, Max

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking something like:

```
    private static class MyExpander implements PathExpander
    {
        private final boolean forward;

        MyExpander( boolean forward )
        {
            this.forward = forward;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterable expand( Path path, BranchState state )
        {
            boolean instance = state.getState();
            if ( !instance && (instance = "instance".equals( path.endNode().getProperty( "type", null )) ) )
                state.setState( instance );
            Direction direction = forward ? OUTGOING : INCOMING;
            return (forward ? instance : !instance) ?
                    path.endNode().getRelationships( direction ) :
                    path.endNode().getRelationships( CONTAINS, direction );
        }

        @Override
        public PathExpander reverse()
        {
            return new MyExpander( !forward );
        }
    }

    TraversalDescription side = traversal( NODE_PATH )
                .expand( new MyExpander( true ), new InitialBranchState.State( FALSE, FALSE ) );

        BidirectionalTraversalDescription traverser = bidirectionalTraversal().collisionEvaluator( new PathEvaluator.Adapter()
        {
            @Override
            public Evaluation evaluate( Path path, BranchState state )
            {
                return Evaluation.ofIncludes( state.getState() );
            }
        } ).mirroredSides( side );
```

Although I noticed that there's a problem with collision evaluator, resulting in an exception. Fixed it locally in the neo4j code base.

Comment: Aren't you use the "MyExpander" class for the same I used the "Evaluator" ? What exactly is the BidirectionalTD doing? Is it for starting from two diffrent points?

Comment: The difference in putting filtering in the expander is that it reduces the number of paths to visit sooner, rather than later in the evaluator (so should be a performance optimization). And yes, the bidirection td will have the traverser start from two points and see where they meet, which also may reduce number of paths to visited drastically in many scenarios.